# Why can't I find my fiddles using 'View My Fiddles'

Tags: extjs, sencha-fiddle

I started using Sencha Fiddle, and I have a hard time to get it work. So far I created two fiddles, but I can access them only via their URL [fiddle 1](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i9m) and [fiddle 2](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j11). But when I want to access them through the user menu *username - View My Fiddles*, I get an empty list *No fiddles found, even though int the Details section, the field *Author* my username is filled with my username.

Comment: I have around 30 fiddles in fiddle.sencha.com and never had the issues your describing, Try going to the url's directly and forking them and then saving again. Should copy the fiddles and link them to your account properly.

Comment: @Scriptable Do you have a paid subscription? I use ExtJs for open source development and have no paid subscription. Maybe this is the explanation? I also noticed that I do not have access to the fiddle documentation.

Comment: No mate, just a standard account

Comment: Do you have access to the documentation?

Comment: Where is the documentation for fiddle? I've never seen it. Do you have a link or something?

Comment: When I hover over the word *Fiddle*, a link *Documentation* appears, when I follow it, it takes me to a *Knowledge Base* (https://kb.sencha.com/#!products/Sencha Fiddle) with no content. When I try to login, it tells me that content is only accessible to users with a valid Sencha Support Portal account.

Comment: Ah ok, I've never noticed that before. Yeah that will be for subscribed customers only. I'm not subscribed to any sencha products so I do not see the documentation but I can still use fiddle.sencha.com without any issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72228/discussion-between-lorenz-meyer-and-scriptable).